# gnuplot: Spurious data points in plots when using index

Tags: indexing, graph, gnuplot

I'm trying to use gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 6 to visualize some data from a file `test.dat` which looks like this:

```
#Pkg 1
type    min max avg
small   1   10  5
medium  5   15  7
large   10  20  15


#Pkg 2
small   3   9   5
medium  5   13  6
large   11  17  13
```

(Note that the values are actually separated by tabs even though it shows as spaces here.)

My gnuplot commands are

```
reset
set datafile separator "\t"
plot 'test.dat' index 0 using 2:xticlabels(1) title col, '' using 3 title col, '' using 4 title col
```

This [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTDnk.png) as long as there is only a single data block in `test.dat`. When I add the second block [spurious data points appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnmpT.png). Why is that and how can it be fixed?

YFTR: Using `stat` on the file yields only expected results. It reports two data blocks for the full file and correct values (for min, max and sum) when I specify one of the two using `index`

Comment: have you tried to repeat the `index 0` specification also in the other parts of the `plot` command, i.e., `'' index 0 using...`?

Comment: That was exactly the problem and I feel really stupid now. Well, maybe others run in a similar problem. Thanks a lot for your help! If you add your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: no problem, glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the comment to the question, one has to explicitly repeat the `index 0` specification within all parts of the `plot` command as

```
plot 'test.dat' index 0 using 2, '' index 0 using 3, ...
```

otherwise `''` refers to all blocks in the data file